# Matlab code conversion to Java in order to run on Apache Spark

Tags: java, matlab, hadoop, apache-spark, distributed-computing

**PROBLEM:**

I have an algorithm (a MATLAB code) and I want to run this algorithm using Apache Spark on a Hadoop cluster. I know that the conversion from MATLAB to Java is possible thanks to MATLAB Builder JA. At this point, I think that my code will run on Apache Spark with my customized configuration.

**QUESTION 1:**

Do this kind of conversion grant me a distributed mode execution on the cluster? I mean, I am not using any RDD or Spark function. I think that the algorithm will run in the same way of a standard Java code.

**QUESTION 2:**

Is there a way to use a MATLAB code (converted in Java or Python code) and run it on Apache Spark in a distributed mode without rewriting the whole MATLAB code in a Java file with RDDs?

Comment: 1) In order to have your code run distributed on the cluster you must use the spark api. i don't think that any code builder will use it.

Comment: @moe I think I have to install the MATLAB Runtime and/or the MATLAB Distributed Computer Server on the nodes of the cluster. I would like to avoid these installations

Comment: Ideally you would be using Datasets in Spark2, not RDDs